# Do you always have to have a root node with xml/xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd

Been looking at a tutorial and it has the following xml and xsd.:

[image: http://yfrog.com/b9xsdandxmlj]

What I was wondering is do you have to use a root node in this example? There doesnt seem to be any xsd type definition that points to the 'employeeS' node.

Do you always have to have a root node in xml or can you just have

```
<xml version="1.0">
<employee><employee>
<employee><employee>
<employee><employee>
```

Comment: I thought a root node was required. Keen to know for sure though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from the XML specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/ (fifth edition) chapter 2

This says

"Each XML document has both a logical and a physical structure. Physically, the document is composed of units called entities. An entity may refer to other entities to cause their inclusion in the document. A document begins in a "root" or document entity."

"[Definition: There is exactly one element, called the root, or document element, no part of which appears in the content of any other element.] For all other elements, if the start-tag is in the content of another element, the end-tag is in the content of the same element. More simply stated, the elements, delimited by start- and end-tags, nest properly within each other."

So basically yes, you always need one root element.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you always have to have a root node. However, you can have a file that holds an XML document *fragment* that is imported into another file as a parsed entity. All the including file needs to do is have a declaration like this in its DTD:

```
<!ENTITY SomeName SYSTEM "/path/to/file.xml">
```

Then it can just wrap it up like this:

```
<SomeOuterTag>
   &SomeName;
</SomeOuterTag>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the brief [description of XML at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling), which summarizes several well-formedness rules from [the official XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-document):

> There is a single "root" element which contains all the other elements.

Comment: wikipedia is not a very strong reference; published spec is the reference...let's say the wiki rewrites the article: your reference would be lost

Comment: @Jaywalker: I'm aware that Wikipedia is "a free online encyclopedia *anyone can edit* " - that's why I'm offering the quote as a convenient summary, followed with a link to the original, authoritative specification (which is slightly more complex). I'm not saying "it's on Wikipedia, it's true!" but "here's a summary (w), here's the canonical source (w3c)". Edited to emphasize the link to source.

Answer (score 2):

Root node is mandatory. It's also referred to as "Document Element" in W3C's nomenclature.

> Definition: There is exactly one element, called the root, or document element, no part of which appears in the content of any other element (reference: [section 2.1 of W3C XML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-document))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are required to have one, and only one root node.