# Root element is missing XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, string, list

I want to read an xml file and use t to generate a pdf file. here is the code :

```
public static List<FichierCTAF> getXmlFCtaf(string pathXml)
        {


            var doc = XDocument.Load(pathXml);
            ...
}
```

But it throws me the exception " Root element is missing" when calling the load method. Help please

Comment: Post (the first part of) the XML file. You are missing a root element.

Comment: I'd say post as much of the XML as possible. You are probably missing an end tag somewhere. You can also check your XML syntax online, just to be sure it's formated correctly.

Comment: yes you are right, sorry i passed the wrong path of the file xml, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Every xml file has to have a **Root Element**, in your case it seems your xml doesn't have any. See this for more info: [Do you always have to have a root node with xml/xsd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304038/do-you-always-have-to-have-a-root-node-with-xml-xsd)