# how to sort xml file in UNIX

Tags: xml, sorting, unix

We have XML file, (Date: DD/MM/YY)

```
<ABT><pid>101</pid><date>10/12/13</date><name>AAA</name></ABT>
<ABT><pid>102</pid><date>11/12/13</date><name>BBB</name></ABT>
<ABT><pid>101</pid><date>09/12/13</date><name>AAA</name></ABT>
<ABT><pid>102</pid><date>24/12/13</date><name>BBB</name></ABT>
<JRE><pid>101</pid><date>01/12/13</date><name>AAA</name></JRE> 
<JRE><pid>102</pid><date>02/12/13</date><name>BBB</name></JRE>
```

output should be as

```
<JRE><pid>101</pid><date>01/12/13</date><name>AAA</name></JRE>
<ABT><pid>101</pid><date>09/12/13</date><name>AAA</name></ABT>
<ABT><pid>101</pid><date>10/12/13</date><name>AAA</name></ABT>
<JRE><pid>102</pid><date>02/12/13</date><name>BBB</name></JRE>
<ABT><pid>102</pid><date>11/12/13</date><name>BBB</name></ABT>
<ABT><pid>102</pid><date>24/12/13</date><name>BBB</name></ABT>
```

How to sort this file based on `<pid>, <date>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `sort` together with `sed`. If you firstly want to order based on `pid` and then on `date`, let's add a space after each one of these tags and then sort accordingly:

```
$ sed -e 's/<pid>/& /' -e 's/<date>/& /' file | sort -nk2 -k3 | sed 's/ //g'
<JRE><pid>101</pid><date>01/12/13</date><name>AAA</name></JRE>
<ABT><pid>101</pid><date>09/12/13</date><name>AAA</name></ABT>
<ABT><pid>101</pid><date>10/12/13</date><name>AAA</name></ABT>
<JRE><pid>102</pid><date>02/12/13</date><name>BBB</name></JRE>
<ABT><pid>102</pid><date>11/12/13</date><name>BBB</name></ABT>
<ABT><pid>102</pid><date>24/12/13</date><name>BBB</name></ABT>
```

First `sed` adds a space before the date and the last one removes it. In between, `sort -n -k2 -k3` sorts numerically (`-n`), firstly based on column 2 (`-k2`) and then on column 3 (`-k3`).

Comment: Thank you for you feedback. i need from sorting out, first one  is "pid" and second one is "date"

Answer (score 3):

### sorting with xidel

This command will use [xidel](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html) to sort the file named `file.xml` according to `pid` and `date`.

```
xidel --xquery 'for $i in doc("file.xml")/* order by $i/pid, $i, $i/date return $i' --output-format xml
```

#### considering the root node

> you always need one root element.

[Link to the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304100/4135606)

So, add the root node to the input:

```
<root>
    <ABT>
        <pid>101</pid>
        <date>10/12/13</date>
        <name>AAA</name>
    </ABT>
    <ABT>
        <pid>102</pid>
        <date>11/12/13</date>
        <name>BBB</name>
    </ABT>
    <ABT>
        <pid>101</pid>
        <date>09/12/13</date>
        <name>AAA</name>
    </ABT>
    <ABT>
        <pid>102</pid>
        <date>24/12/13</date>
        <name>BBB</name>
    </ABT>
    <JRE>
        <pid>101</pid>
        <date>01/12/13</date>
        <name>AAA</name>
    </JRE> 
    <JRE>
        <pid>102</pid>
        <date>02/12/13</date>
        <name>BBB</name>
    </JRE>
</root>
```

Note: anyway xidel can handle this multiple root structure.

In case that all nodes which are the direct children of the root node have `<pid>` and `<date>` as *children*.

And your input XML file is named `file.xml`.

This command will return the top nodes after sorting according to their children whose names are `<pid>` and `<date>`, using [xidel](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html).

```
xidel --xquery '<root>
                {for $i in doc("file.xml")/*/*
                order by $i/pid, $i, $i/date
                return $i}
                </root>' --output-format xml
```

command in one line:

```
xidel --xquery '<root>{for $i in doc("file.xml")/*/* order by $i/pid, $i, $i/date return $i}</root>' --output-format xml
```