# How can I POST a list of Elements without Root item as xml in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, simple-framework

I'm trying to POST a entity to a REST endpoint with Retrofit. I have no control over the endpoint code.

The entity consists of a list of objects of another entity.

```
public class DemoEntity {
  @ElementList(inline = true);
  private List<SubEntry> entries;
}

@Root(name = "subEntry")
public class SubEntry {
  @Attribute(name = "attr")
  private String attribute;
}
```

I want the resulting xml to look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"...>
<subEntry attr="a" />
<subEntry attr="b" />
<subEntry attr="c" />
```

But the serializer always includes the root element of DemoEntity.

```
<?xml version="1.0"... ?>
<DemoEntity>
  <subEntry attr="a" />
  <subEntry attr="b" />
  <subEntry attr="c" />
</DemoEntity>
```

Is there any way to circumvent the default (and correct) behaviour to "ignore" the root element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serializer seems to follow the official spec for XML. You can check that following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304038/do-you-always-have-to-have-a-root-node-with-xml-xsd). So basically for a well formed XML and compliant with the standard you need a root element.

What I can suggest is, if your really need to jump over the standard, you can:

1. Build some processor that reading this annotations produce the output you want.
2. Compose your document manually as strings and post it as the body for your request.

I would suggest firstly if the endpoint you are accessing really uses a non-compliant xml, just before going with a harder solution.