# How to write xml file with multiple root element using ElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have python script and I have already written logic of writing xml file using `xml.etree.cElementTree` and the logic is look like below

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")
for I in range(0,10):
    ET.SubElement(root, "field1").text = "some value1"
    ET.SubElement(root, "field2").text = "some vlaue2"

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

and it give output like

```
<root>
      <field1>some value1</field1>
      <field2>some value2</field2>
      <field1>some value1</field1>
      <field2>some value2</field2>
      <field1>some value1</field1>
      <field2>some value2</field2>
      <field1>some value1</field1>
      <field2>some value2</field2>......
</root>
```

but I want to add multiple root and need out put like below

```
<root>
  <field1>some value1</field1>
  <field2>some value2</field2>
</root>
<root>
  <field1>some value1</field1>
  <field2>some value2</field2>
</root>
<root>
  <field1>some value1</field1>
  <field2>some value2</field2>
</root>
<root>
  <field1>some value1</field1>
  <field2>some value2</field2>
</root>
```

is it possible to write like above file using `xml.etree.cElementTree` in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to generate is not valid xml.
See [Do you always have to have a root node with xml/xsd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304038/do-you-always-have-to-have-a-root-node-with-xml-xsd) for more info.

Also you can always manually concatenate the string.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
result= ''
for I in range(0, 10):
    root = ET.Element("root")
    ET.SubElement(root, "field1").text = "some value1"
    ET.SubElement(root, "field2").text = "some vlaue2"
    result += ET.tostring(root)
print(result) # or write the result to a file
```