# Modify entire XML attributes then merge all results into one XML

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I am writing ElementTree python code that will:

1. Modify itemID in the xml and write to disk.
2. Go to next itemID in itemIDList modify itemID in xml and write to disk

The problem is that the XML gets overwritten over and over and what I want is to append the data to end of new xml file.

This is my code so far.

```
base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
xml_file = os.path.join(base_path, 'data.xml')
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:

    d = f.readlines()
    itemIDlist = []
    for i in range(len(d)-1):
        hold = d[i].split('\n')
        itemIDlist.append(str(hold[0]))
        for e in root.iter():

            if 'itemID' in e.keys():
                e.set('itemID', itemIDlist[i])
                new_data = ET.tostringlist(root)
                new_xml = open('newXml.xml', 'w')
                new_xml.write(new_data)
```

The text file has a list of numbers like these; we call it a.txt

```
19283
29354
34958
59854
```

The original XML file looks like this

```
    <requests>
    <inventory name="WaterMelon" itemID="6834833" action="inStock">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager"/>
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory name="StrawBerry" itemID="9283343" action="inStock">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager"/>
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory name="WaterMelon" itemID="" action="inStock">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager"/>
        </user>
    </inventory>-->
</requests>
```

Currently I get four different files, however, I just want to get one XML file containing all the results. It should look like this

```
<requests>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="19283" name="WaterMelon">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="19283" name="StrawBerry">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="19283" name="WaterMelon">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>-->

    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="29354" name="WaterMelon">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="29354" name="StrawBerry">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="29354" name="WaterMelon">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>-->

    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="34958" name="WaterMelon">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="34958" name="StrawBerry">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="34958" name="WaterMelon">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>-->
</requests>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link had the same problem. 
[How to write xml file with multiple root element using ElementTree in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261681/how-to-write-xml-file-with-multiple-root-element-using-elementtree-in-python)

I concatenated the strings.

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:

d = f.readlines()
itemIDlist = []
new_data = ''
for i in range(len(d)-1):
    hold = d[i].split('\n')
    itemIDlist.append(str(hold[0]))
    for e in root.iter():

        if 'itemID' in e.keys():
            e.set('itemID', itemIDlist[i])

    new_data += ET.tostring(root)
new_xml = open('newXml.xml', 'w')
new_xml.write(new_data)
```

This gives us the expected result; one xml file.

```
    <requests>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="19283" name="WaterMelon">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="19283" name="StrawBerry">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="19283" name="WaterMelon">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>--&gt;
</requests><requests>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="29354" name="WaterMelon">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="29354" name="StrawBerry">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="29354" name="WaterMelon">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>--&gt;
</requests><requests>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="34958" name="WaterMelon">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="34958" name="StrawBerry">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>
    <inventory action="inStock" itemID="34958" name="WaterMelon">
        <user username="Carlos">
            <role name="GeneralManager" />
        </user>
    </inventory>--&gt;
</requests>
```

There is still a problem, when xml is generated there is a > which does not get interpreted properly and outputs
`&gt;` instead of `>.`